# Fastest way to store and retrieve value by two integer keys

Tags: c#, performance, hashtable

I need to super fast store and retrieve values by two integer keys.

So I have input values `uint Id1, uint Id2` and need to get `uint Count`.

Also I know max value of `Id1` and `Id2` (it is about 5 000 000).

My current implementation takes about 70% of application work time and it might be a few days.

It just use standard .net dictionaries and of course can be improved. But I guess it is a very useful operation in computer science and no doubt more efficient algorithms exists.

Here is my implementation

```
void Main()
{
    var rep = new Repository();

    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();

    for (uint i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        for (uint j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
        {
            rep.Add(new DomainEntity(){Id1 = i, Id2 = j, Count = 1});
        }
    }

    for (uint i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        for (uint j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
        {
            rep.GetDomainEntityByIds(i,j);
        }
    }

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine ("Elapsed:{0}", sw.Elapsed);
}

public class Repository
{
        private readonly Dictionary<Tuple<UInt32, UInt32>, UInt32> _dictStore;

        public Repository()
        {
            _dictStore = new Dictionary<Tuple<uint, uint>, uint>();
        }

        public uint Add(DomainEntity item)
        {
            var entry = MapToTableEntry(item);
            _dictStore.Add(entry.Key,entry.Value);
            return 0;
        }

        public void Update(DomainEntity item)
        {
            var entry = MapToTableEntry(item);
            _dictStore[entry.Key] = entry.Value;
        }

        public IEnumerable<DomainEntity> GetAllItems()
        {
            return _dictStore.Select(MapToDomainEntity);
        }

        public DomainEntity GetDomainEntityByIds(uint articleId1, uint articleId2)
        {
            var tuple = new Tuple<uint, uint>(articleId1, articleId2);

            if (_dictStore.ContainsKey(tuple))
            {
                return MapToDomainEntity(new KeyValuePair<Tuple<uint, uint>, uint>(tuple, _dictStore[tuple]));
            }

            return null;
        }

        private KeyValuePair<Tuple<uint, uint>, uint> MapToTableEntry(DomainEntity item)
        {
            return new KeyValuePair<Tuple<uint, uint>, uint>(new Tuple<uint, uint>(item.Id1,item.Id2), item.Count);
        }

        private DomainEntity MapToDomainEntity(KeyValuePair<Tuple<uint, uint>, uint> entry)
        {
            return new DomainEntity
            {
                Id1 = entry.Key.Item1,
                Id2 = entry.Key.Item2,
                Count = entry.Value,
            };
        }
}

public class DomainEntity
{
        public uint Id1 { get; set; }
        public uint Id2 { get; set; }
        public uint Count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with directly using a Dictionary<Tuple<uint,uint>,uint>? How many lookup operations per second are you getting and what number would you expect?

Comment: also, what does the profiler say? Where is your bottleneck?

Comment: @Axarydax i want to get as much operations as possible because in my current implementation application takes DAYS to process data. It is really slow. And 70% of time takes Repository.

Comment: @Axarydax profiler says that problem in Update and GetDomainEmtityByIds methods. GetDomainEmtityByIds is most heavy method.

Comment: and what happens in GetDomainEntityByIds() according to the profiler? Is the hash calculation for Tuple<uint,uint> taking the most time?

Comment: "How to improve my current implementation"-questions belong to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (voted for off-topic).

Comment: @Axarydax i donnt know because i used limited free profiler.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter it doesnt only "how to improve" question. I am looking best solution for my problem(i guess many people might have simular tasks) and i put here my solution as example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is create an efficient dictionary using an efficient key & hash. Since the dictionary always uses a 32 bit value and you have around 45 bits of data, you can't create a unique hash, but you should do your best.

- Always use TryGetValue() rather than a double lookup.
- When using dictionaries with value type keys, use a custom IEqualityComparer passed as the argument to the dictionary constructor.
- Use a custom hash code to try to squeeze the maximum amount of information from the subkeys into the 32 bit hash.

Example:

```
public class Storage 
{
   private Dictionary<Key, DomainObject> dict;

   public Storage()
   {
      dict = new Dictionary<Key, DomainObject>(Key.Comparer.Instance)
   }

   public DomainObject Get(uint a, uint b)
   {
      DomainObject obj;
      dict.TryGetValue(new Key(a,b), out obj);
      return obj;
   }

   internal struct Key 
   {
       internal readonly uint a;
       internal readonly uint b;

       public Key(uint a, uint b)
       {
          this.a = a;
          this.b = b;
       }     

       internal class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Key>
       {
           internal static readonly Comparer Instance = new Comparer();
           private Comparer(){}

           public bool Equals(Key x, Key y)
           {  
               return x.a == y.a && x.b == y.b;
           }  

           public int GetHashCode(Key x)
           {    
              return (int)((x.a & 0xffff) << 16) | (x.b & 0xffff));
           }
       } 
   }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed Tuple to Key and it gives very good perfomance improvement(31 vs 2 seconds). I cannt understand what is wrong with Tuple?

Comment: The main problem with using tuples is that the default Tuple<> is a reference type so you allocate a reference object every time you create a key. The key here is a pure value type and small enough (64 bits) that it is probably useful to pass it around as a value type. The Key type in my example is essentially exactly a tuple but as a struct, and using its own equality comparer to avoid boxing in the dictionary. It may be a micro-optimization that isn't worthwile, but I have found it worthwile on several occasions.

Comment: I believe the biggest performance problem with `Tuple` is the boxing involved in the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods.

Answer (score 5):

One minor(?) improvement, you can use [`TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) to avoid to lookup the dictionary twice:

```
public DomainEntity GetDomainEntityByIds(uint articleId1, uint articleId2)
{
    var tuple = new Tuple<uint, uint>(articleId1, articleId2);
    uint value;
    if (_dictStore.TryGetValue(tuple, out value))
    {
        return MapToDomainEntity(new KeyValuePair<Tuple<uint, uint>, uint>(tuple, value));
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: It is a very good improvement. 31 vs 44 seconds on my computer.

Comment: Tuples hash poorly.  You can get lots of collisions

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lot of extra work in there, converting to and from `KeyValuePair`. Also,  `DomainEntity` is a reference type, so you probably should just store references to those in the dictionary rather than having to create them from the key and value every time you look one up.

Create your dictionary as:

```
var _dictStore = new Dictionary<Tuple<uint, uint>, DomainEntity>();
```

Then:

```
public uint Add(DomainEntity item)
{
    var key = new Tuple<uint, uint>(item.Id1, item.Id2);
    _dictStore.Add(key, item);
    return 0;
}
```

And lookup:

```
public DomainEntity GetDomainEntityByIds(uint articleId1, uint articleId2)
{
    var key = new Tuple<uint, uint>(articleId1, articleId2);
    DomainEntity value;
    if (!_dictStore.TryGetValue(key, out value))
    {
        value = null;
    }
    return value;
}
```